# Solving Laplace equation with Gauss Seidel and ghost point for boundary points

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Error

error = 0

#Set Maximum Iteration

maxIter = 500

#Set Dimension and Delta

lenX = lenY = 1
delta = 0.1


#Initial guess of interior grid

Tguess = 0

#Set meshgrid

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0.1,1.2,delta),np.arange(0.1,1.2,delta))

Tx = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2]

#Texact
Texact = np.empty((13,13))
Texact.fill(Tguess)
for jx in np.arange(0.1,1.3,0.1) :
    for jy in np.arange(0.1,1.3,0.1):
        Texact = ((np.cos((np.pi)*jx))*(np.sinh((np.pi)*jy)))/(np.sinh(np.pi))

#Set array size and set the interior value with Tguess

T = np.empty((13,13))
T.fill(Tguess)
Tnew = np.empty((13,13))
Tnew.fill(Tguess)

#Set boundary condition
T[0:1 , 11: ] = np.cos ((np.pi))
T[1:1, : ] = T [ 11 :11 , : ]    
T[1 : 1 , 1 : 1] = 0

#Iteration           
print ("Please wait for a moment")
nof = 0
Tnew = T
Tnew = T .copy()
while (error < 10**(-7)) :
    for i in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13):
        for j in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13):
            Tnew[i,j]= (0.25 * (T[i+1,j] + Tnew[i-1,j])+(0.25 *( T[i,j+1] + Tnew[i,j-1])))
            T[0 , j ] = T [1 ,j ]
            T[12 , j ] = T[10,j]
            error = np.abs((Texact) - (Tnew))
            nof = nof + 1

print(nof)                          
print("Iteration finished")
```

I'm trying to solve Laplace equation with the methods that i said
but my code doesn't converge.
Domain of problem is 1-1 and mesh size is 11*11.
We have to use number of each points that updated in last iteration especially i-1 and j-1 which updated before and use these number to Tnew.
I want to number of iteration and error that must be lower than 10 ** -2 but it doesn't in my code.
In the top of the domain we have dirichlet b.c that is cos(pi) and bottom of it must be 0.
Right and left wall must be Neumann b.c. (derivation of T in terms of x must be 0 in this case we have to use Gauss point i+1 and i-1 that should be update with a function that i dont know how should i write it and Neumann b.c. is Ti+1 - Ti-1 =0.
Our domain is 1-1 with 11 points by 0.1 step.